# How to find differences between 2 CVS branches?

Tags: cvs

Is there a command in CVS that can list the differences between 2 branches.  By differences I mean a list of files that are different or present in one branch and not the other.  If so could you please provider an example?

Comment: That CVS? Really? Last release `May 8, 2008; 15 years ago`. It's dead.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I'm writing an answer to the same end, but that doesn't help anyone if OP has a legacy repo that they need to at least understand.

Comment: That's true. But it does not change the reality. CVS is dead and maybe OP missed that? Who knows. As for scripts/tools I'd rather look for a way to migrate the repo anyway

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - We do have a legacy repo and fairy large one. Being just a developer I do not have the option of migrating such a large repo just to compare 2 branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to do something quick and with very limited knowledge of CVS and GIT and having to deal with a repo that contains hundred of projects, did a kludge like the following:

```
export CVSROOT=:pserver:user@cvsserver.com:/path/to/cvsrep
cvs login
cvs export -r HEAD project-name
cvs export -r Branch project-name
```

Once I had both branches exported, used BeyondCompare to compare the 2 folders.  That seems to be give me what I need.

Comment: `git cvsimport -C project-name -d :pserver:user@cvsserver.com:/path/to/cvsrep; git diff HEAD Branch` does not work :(?

Comment: I am getting a 'AuthReply: E PAM authenticate error: Permission denied' error when I do that.  Need some additional set up?

Comment: ah, in that case, you need to run the `export…` and `cvs login` before `git cvsimport…`

Comment: I did run the [export] and [cvs login] prior to running the command.  But still get the authentication error

Comment: huh! OK, I never had PAM be involved, so I must admit I'm in over my head, and must also admit your method is better – it works.

Comment: I am not an experienced user of either git or cvs.  I will try to get your solution to work.  It will come in handy in future without having to resort to an external tool.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In all honesty, the CVS project hasn't seen an update in 15 years. So, investing time in learning to use it is probably a bad idea.

I'd forget about wrangling with CVS directly; instead I'd import the CVS repo into git, [`git cvsimport`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cvsimport) `-d CVSROOT`.

Once you have that git repository,

```bash
git diff branch1 branch2
```

will work just beautifully.

So, all in all,

```bash
git cvsimport -C baz-module -d :pserver:anonymous@cvs.ancientsoftware.org:/cvs/reallyoldsoftware foo/bar/baz-module
cd baz-module
git diff branch1 branch2
```

Comment: I am not trying to learn CVS at all.  Unfortunately I am in a project that is till using CVS. So  sometimes there are tasks like these that need to be done.

Comment: yeah, as said, do them through imports into git. CVS isn't very advanced, I think your other option is literally to check out both branches into different local directories, and compare the directory contents. You know how I would do that? Right. I'd make one of them a git repo, commit its state, check out a new git branch, delete all files and copy over the other checkout, commit that, and then do a `git diff` on the two git branches…

Comment: But `git cvsimport` is much better. You can compare the file contents, but you can also figure out who changed what at what point within the same environment.

Comment: I ended up exporting both branches of a project and used BeyondCompare.  I will however keep in mind what you have said for future.  Thank you.